# Fixing missing windows files by re-installing it

Tags: windows, windows-10

In my SSD drive's windows 10, it seems some system files are deleted or damaged. so the windows 10 will not boot and I will get a winload.exe blue screen boot error.

Is there any way to re-install windows 10 so that the missing files fix and I can run my old windows again? I have so many softwares configured there.

Comment: There is no way to do an in-place repair installation from outside of Windows. If you were to install Windows by booting to install media you would end up getting a fresh installation. However, it sounds like you should, replace the SSD anyways

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound that reinstall is the correct approach. You might try starting with a Windows USB Key and see if you can somehow replace the drivers. That seems doubtful but you can see it it might work.

Comment: To be clear this reinstall would be on a new drive, even if you were to reinstall on the same drive, there is no way to keep your data due to how Windows has failed

Comment: Program configuration are stored as files in the user account folder or in `C:\ProgramData` both locations allow to migrate the settings to a new installation. And if settings are store in registry you can mount the registry hive and export relevant parts to a reg text file and import it on a new system. If you want to keep your Windows installation with all configurations next time perform a full backup regularly (using an image based backup software), then you can restore it at any time.

Comment: Thank you very much my friends :) I re-install the whole windows again.

Comment: @Robert - You can only mount registry hive from another machine in read only mode.

Comment: @Ramhound yes I know that but for exporting it to a reg file read-only mode is sufficient. Once the new system is installed you can selectively import the registry paths from the reg file you need (use a text editor and remove unneeded parts).

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid you must do a clean install of Windows 10 on a separate hard drive. When you reach your new operating system then mount your old hard drive and copy off all the important files.